# SQL*PLUS SET Command

Tags: sqlplus

Kindly remind me of how to set a pagesize to properly display rows in the command below;
SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES;
The rows fetched are displayed accordingly.

Thanks

Comment: [Top link on Google](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus-set.html); I've got it bookmarked. It's very useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format query results in SQL*Plus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669712/format-query-results-in-sqlplus)

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
set PAGESIZE 60;
set LINESIZE 132;
```